# How to encrypt password in SSIS script task?

Tags: c#, encryption, ssis, script-task

So I have a script task in an SSIS package that accesses email.

```
  ExchangeService service = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
  service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@domain.com", "123");
```

I have encrypted the package itself, but am still feeling uneasy that it's in plain text on the ScriptMain.cs page.  In the past I was able to encrypt this data on say WPF applications, but not sure how that can translate to a script task.  Am I over thinking this?  Is there a way to set this up in connection managers or something else that would add one more layer of protection?

I wanted to add I'm using the exchange services API to connect to the email.

Answer (score 1):

You can use so called sensitive package or project parameters; environment params mapped to such params are stored in SSIS Catalog encrypted. Just create one for your password and get it in your Script task with `.GetSensitiveValue()` method like

```
Dts.Variables["$Package::YourPassword"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString()
```

as described by [Matt Masson](http://www.mattmasson.com/2012/01/retrieving-the-value-of-a-sensitive-parameter-in-a-script/).

Comment: This apparently is only available in the [project deployment mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-2017#compare-project-deployment-model-and-legacy-package-deployment-model). I wonder how to achieve it in the package deployment mode too?

Answer (score 0):

According to  [EWS Managed API clients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx) , 'Domain-joined clients that target an on-premises Exchange server can use the default credentials of the user who is logged on, assuming the credentials are associated with a mailbox'

So you may be able to use;

```
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

If that isn't possible, I'd recommend storing it in a database to be retrieved. You'll be able to secure/encrypt it in a Database.

Also, if you're using SQL 2012 or later, you could use a sensitive parameter. This is assuming you want to parameterize the password and/or username.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            string value = Dts.Variables["$Package::ExchangePassword"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString();

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Dts.Log(e.Message, 0, null);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
    }
```